# Get matching and non-matching words from strings in pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to compare strings for similarity within the same pandas column to derive one string with all of the matching words and a second string with all non-matching words based on the value above or below in the index.

I would chose whether to match with the above or below based on which one has more matching words.

Here is a small example:

Before:

| Product Description |
| --- |
| Red HMS Carabiner |
| Blue HMS Carabiner |
| HMS Carabiner Orange |
| Liquid Chalk - 100ml |
| Liquid Chalk - 100ml (Case of 10) |

After:

| Product Description | Variance |
| --- | --- |
| HMS Carabiner | Red |
| HMS Carabiner | Blue |
| HMS Carabiner | Orange |
| Liquid Chalk - 100ml | Nan |
| Liquid Chalk - 100ml | (Case of 10) |

I'm at a bit of a loss on where to start so my apologies for not beginning with an attempted solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compare sets of words with the previous and the next product
2. Choose which neighbour has larger intersection
3. Choose the words that didn't get into intersections as Variance

This works for your example, but may give strange output when there're multiple repeating words in the product descriptions.

I also assumed that if the description doesn't have common words with either neighbours, it doesn't have a group and therefore variance.

```
def get_intersection(descr1, descr2):
    if pd.isna(descr1) or pd.isna(descr2):
        return set()
    return set(descr1.split()).intersection(set(descr2.split()))

def get_unique_words(descr, intersection):
    unique_words = " ".join(
        word for word in descr.split() if word not in intersection
    )
    if len(unique_words) > 0:
        return unique_words

def get_unique_description(row):
    if len(row["next_product_intersection"]) == 0 and len(row["prev_product_intersection"]) == 0:
        return row["Product Description"]
    
    if len(row["next_product_intersection"]) >= len(row["prev_product_intersection"]):
        return row["next_product_unique_words"]
    
    return row["prev_product_unique_words"]


df["next_product"] = df["Product Description"].shift(-1)
df["prev_product"] = df["Product Description"].shift(1)

df["next_product_intersection"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: get_intersection(row["Product Description"], row["next_product"]),
    axis=1
)
df["prev_product_intersection"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: get_intersection(row["Product Description"], row["prev_product"]),
    axis=1
)

df["next_product_unique_words"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: get_unique_words(row["Product Description"], row["next_product_intersection"]),
    axis=1
)
df["prev_product_unique_words"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: get_unique_words(row["Product Description"], row["prev_product_intersection"]),
    axis=1
)

df["Variance"] = df.apply(get_unique_description, axis=1)
df = df[["Product Description", "Variance"]]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Product Description      Variance
0                  Red HMS Carabiner           Red
1                 Blue HMS Carabiner          Blue
2               HMS Carabiner Orange        Orange
3               Liquid Chalk - 100ml          None
4  Liquid Chalk - 100ml (Case of 10)  (Case of 10)
```

Comment: This works as expected and is extremely helpful. Is there a way to augment it with a filter that only considers it a variance if it has at least _n_ similar words.

For the real world example: Some product descriptions in my actual set have a brand name of up 3 or even 4 words and therefore completely different products are showing in variance vs. single.

It may be easier to strip brands at this stage but I'm curious if that could be added into this solution.

Thank you sincerely for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve your problem:

```py
import difflib
import pandas as pd


def get_products_variants(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Get variants for every product description.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        A `pandas.DataFrame` with a column named "Product Description",
        that contains every existing product description.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        A `pandas.DataFrame` with the columns:
            - "Product Description": The common name between variants of same product.
            - "Variance": The product variant.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...     {
    ...         "Product Description": [
    ...             "Red HMS Carabiner", "Blue HMS Carabiner", "HMS Carabiner Orange",
    ...             "Liquid Chalk - 100ml", "Liquid Chalk - 100ml (Case of 10)"
    ...         ]
    ...     }
    ... )
    >>> get_products_variants(test_df)
         Product Description      Variance
    0          HMS Carabiner           Red
    1          HMS Carabiner          Blue
    2          HMS Carabiner        Orange
    9   Liquid Chalk - 100ml              
    10  Liquid Chalk - 100ml  (Case of 10)
    """
    new_data = []

    for description in df["Product Description"].values:
        # Split product descriptions into different words
        words = description.split(" ")
        # Find product descriptions that are closely related to the current
        # product description.
        matches = difflib.get_close_matches(description, df["Product Description"].values)

        # Iterate the descriptions that are similar to current product description
        # to find the words that exist in all product descriptions
        for descr in matches:
            descr_words = descr.split(" ")
            _words = []
            for word in descr_words:
                if word in words:
                    _words.append(word)
            words = _words

        # This new description is comprised of words that exist in all product descriptions
        # that have similar names.
        new_description = " ".join(words)

        # Find the words that are unique to each product description.
        # These words will be the variants
        for descr in matches:
            variance = descr.replace(new_description, "").strip()
            new_data.append([new_description, variance])

    # Create new dataframe with results
    return pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=["Product Description", "Variance"]).drop_duplicates()


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Product Description": [
            "Red HMS Carabiner", "Blue HMS Carabiner", "HMS Carabiner Orange",
            "Liquid Chalk - 100ml", "Liquid Chalk - 100ml (Case of 10)"
        ]
    }
)
new_df = get_products_variants(df)
new_df
# Returns:
#
#      Product Description      Variance
# 0          HMS Carabiner           Red
# 1          HMS Carabiner          Blue
# 2          HMS Carabiner        Orange
# 9   Liquid Chalk - 100ml              
# 10  Liquid Chalk - 100ml  (Case of 10)
```

**Output:**

|  | Product Description | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | HMS Carabiner | Red |
| 1 | HMS Carabiner | Blue |
| 2 | HMS Carabiner | Orange |
| 9 | Liquid Chalk - 100ml |  |
| 10 | Liquid Chalk - 100ml | (Case of 10) |

### Notes

To find similar product descriptions, we use the `get_close_matches` function from `difflib` module (a module that comes with Python by default).
Depending on the product descriptions, `get_close_matches` might not find all the similar product descriptions that a certain product has. In other words, **the above solution is not guaranteed to work for all situations.**